# I can't turn on wifi after installed Ubuntu

Tags: wireless

It shows that my laptop is now airplane mode, i can't turn on wifi. After i turned off the airplane mode, still can't turn on wifi. What is the problem?

Comment: Can you paste the result of `lspci | grep -i net`. Also please check if your machine have any hardware wifi toggle button. If yes, make sure it is turned on.

Answer (score 1):

try restart. try `sudo rfkill unblock wifi`

Answer (score 0):

Installed ubuntu on toshiba click2pro and hardware switch disabled appeared. Opened the laptop and removed the battery connection and put it back and everything is good to go. Bios was altered and it was set back. Made my day going.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @A.B. I don't see how this isn't an answer. If he was able to fix the issue by just opening up the laptop and disconnecting/reconnecting the power, then that's an answer.